# Python / Opencv How to draw a mesh surface having stl file

Tags: numpy, opencv, mesh

I need to draw the surface triangles from a mesh that I've stored in different formats such as xyz or stl. My final purpose is create a binary image with the triangles in order to be able to overlay other images that I've already produced in another python script.

I don't know what is the best approach. Using the numpy-stl module it is possible extrating the vectors and points, but i'm not being able to produce a opencv code. I tried polylines.

These are my files .

Stl - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7...

xyz - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7...

I did some code with opencv without any success.

```
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh
#import stl

from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from matplotlib import pyplot
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    your_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('stlMidpoint.stl')
    img= cv2.imread('nimg.jpg')  #an image with the same size, and I'll use the mesh-mask on this image
    imgMask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")*255
    m_img= np.ones(imgMask.shape, dtype="uint8") * 255

    points = np.array(your_mesh.vectors[0,:,:])
    cv2.polylines( m_img,[points], 1, (255,255,255))

    cv2.imwrite('meshTri.jpg', m_img)
```

Comment: You could do it in Mayavi. See this link `http://www.junweihuang.info/blog/?p=347` for a very short example that converts STL to a Mayavi visualization.

Comment: I want something simpler.
I just want to use the triangulation, I do not want the 3D. I just need the triangles to use them as a mask.

Comment: can you show how you tried the polylines?

Comment: If you look at the code I mentioned above, you'll see the triangles.

Comment: No, I wasn't able to see.
    if strarray[0]=='vertex':
IndexError: list index out of range

I'd like to create an array with the image of the triangles

Comment: @roadrunner66 I converted my stl into binary stl and it worked.
However I don't need all the information. I just need the top face and not the texture, I need the lines.
I want to use the surface of the mesh to overlay on different images.
I want use the triangles on the surface as one layer to apply in different images, which are layers.
This mesh ( I don't know if you have take a look) is from a PCB. A PCB has different copper layers.
I want to apply the mesh to different copper layers, and later calculate all the seconds moments per triangle (each triangle will represent an element)

Comment: @roadrunner66 if you take a look on my files they are huge to use as ascii.
I'm tryng use numpy-stl to extract the basic information, till now without any success